# Increase intervals between processing attempts for service bus triggered azure function

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, azure-durable-functions

I have Service Bus Triggered Azure Function which processes incoming messages. It has usual 10 attempts before message ends up in DLQ. To process the message the function reads information from database.

Problem is that incoming message and information in database appear almost at the same time. And as a result some of messages are being transferred to DLQ because they execute their 10 attempts too fast.

Is believe that adding `await Task.Delay(1000)` after failed attempt will solve the problem.

Is it a good idea? It is not going to block instance from processing other incoming messages in the queue, right?

Comment: could please share the code you used

Comment: @Sampath I can't do it. I do not own that code. Which part you are interested in?

Comment: Do you own the code that publishes these messages, or just the consumer?

Comment: Can the publisher modify their code to add a delay while writing the message to service bus? Then the message will only appear after the delay.  https://medium.com/event-driven-utopia/azure-service-bus-essentials-scheduled-messages-98fd542f9d55. No code changes required at receiver end.

Answer (score 1):

If messages are published at the same time as data is stored in the database, adding a delay when processing messages is not the best strategy since writing to the database could take longer than the delay you'll add. You need a back off strategy.

Ideally, a system should write the data and then send/publish a message. If that's not the case, you need to account for the scenario that a message will arrive but the data won't be there, and it could be for longer that just a second or two. There are a few ways to handle it.

1. Postpone processing
2. Use recoverability
3. Abandon message with a custom delay*

#1 When receiving the message, check if the necessary data is there. If it's not, defer the message and schedule a new message with the deferred message Sequence number in the future to be able to process the deferred message. See [Message Referral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral) for more info.

Since you're using durable functions, it has timers and delays you could explore as well.

#2 In case you might have data immediately in some cases, and in some cases it could be delayed, you could get away with recoverability, where immediate retries would be augmented with delayed retries. You can find more details in my [blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/recoverability-with-azure-functions-delayed-retries).

#3 is not an option until the service implements [this feature](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/454).